# Rundeck 2.5.1 - No matched nodes on locally executed job

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-10.04

I'm working with Rundeck v2.5.1 and I'm trying to configure a job which is executed locally. The job runs an inline script which runs another script. When I run the job (as admin), it seems as though Rundeck doesn't run any of the inline script. Here is the output from the job:

```
com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.NodesetEmptyException: No matched nodes: MultiNodeSelector{nodenames=[localhost]}
 at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.NodeFirstWorkflowStrategy.validateNodeSet(NodeFirstWorkflowStrategy.java:341)
 at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.NodeFirstWorkflowStrategy.executeWorkflowImpl(NodeFirstWorkflowStrategy.java:84)
 at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.BaseWorkflowStrategy.executeWorkflow(BaseWorkflowStrategy.java:182)
 at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.WorkflowExecutionServiceThread.run(WorkflowExecutionServiceThread.java:55)
Exception: class com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.NodesetEmptyException: No matched nodes: MultiNodeSelector{nodenames=[localhost]}
No matched nodes: MultiNodeSelector{nodenames=[localhost]}
```

also, here is the admin.aclpolicy (/etc/rundeck/admin.aclpolicy)

```
description: Admin, all access.
context:
  project: '.*' # all projects
for:
  resource:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/create all kinds
  adhoc:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/running/killing adhoc jobs
  job:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/write/delete/run/kill of all jobs
  node:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/run for all nodes
by:
  group: admin


---


description: Admin, all access.
context:
  application: 'rundeck'
for:
  resource:
    - allow: '*' # allow create of projects
  project:
    - allow: '*' # allow view/admin of all projects
  storage:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/create/update/delete for all /keys/* storage content
by:
  group: admin
```

Rundeck is running on an EC2 instance in a VPC. The instance is running ubuntu 14.04.2 lts. After connecting to the instance via ssh, I can successfully curl Rundeck.

```
$ curl -I -L localhost:4440
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=s1uqcqv0n9h0p4t49m8j2sxx;Path=/
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Location: http://localhost:4440/user/login;jsessionid=s1uqcqv0n9h0p4t49m8j2sxx
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(7.6.0.v20120127)


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 5260
Server: Jetty(7.6.0.v20120127)
```

I've been looking around here and other groups/places but I haven't really been able to find anything that matches up with what I'm experiencing and the Rundeck version.

Has anyone using Rundeck 2.5.1 seen this type of error before/know how I can get this job running?

<3 
mikey

Answer (score 4):

I just ran in to the exact same problem. I got it working by enabling

> Include Server Node: Yes

in your main `Resource Model Source` under your project configuration.

Comment: thanks so much for the response! I checked the config and sure enough I could see `resources.source.1.config.includeServerNode=false`. I changed it to `resources.source.1.config.includeServerNode=true` to no avail. The behaviour hasn't changed :(

Comment: Where is this set?  This answer is painfully close to being helpful.

Comment: Apologues for the long, long, long delay in response. Though I can't remember where exactly this was set, I think it was probably in the [project.properties](http://rundeck.org/docs/administration/configuration-file-reference.html#project.properties) file, which is typically in `/etc/rundeck/project.properties`
<3

Comment: You may have to add a File resource model if you are missing it. The setting "Include Server Node" is inside this resource model.

Comment: Wow! That's fantastic advice, @JefClaes did this work for you?

Answer (score 3):

I had to add `Local` to the `Node Sources` in `Project Settings`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing and I'm glad you managed to get something running :) 

I think this may have worked in my situation, but it's impossible to tell now. With that in mind, do you think it would also work in a situation where you want to target multiple nodes, including the local node, using the MultiNodeSelector?

Answer (score 2):

Please monitor `/var/log/rundeck/rundeck.audit.log` file for a while to get the right reason. It would give you more clues. Most likely your problem is similar to the one described below.

I've faced this problem with job created from API. The thing with rundeck is that it has separate ACL policy for API tokens, which don't really rely on groups of users issuing API tokens. This was out of common sense and a bit surprising, but nevertheless, i've got it working. If the problem setting is the same (job created from API), then try looking at `/etc/rundeck/apitoken.aclpolicy` and make sure that it has `allow: [read,run]` for node by api_token_group.

Comment: Unfortunetly this job was not created from the API. Also I no longer have access to this Rundeck as I now work somewhere else. I hope they solved the problem. Thank you for your answer and great suggestion about monitoring the logs though

Answer (score -2):

I've just created new project for local tasks.

Comment: Great story.  Thanks for sharing, but I have to ask... what does this have to do with... well, the question in particular, or anything at all in general?

Comment: @HopelessN00b It looks like an answer to me. It's probably not the ideal way to do it, but ...

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'll defer to your superior knowledge of Rundeck, but my reading of the question is that running this as a local task is failing, which is problem, making this answer the equivalent of "it works for me!"  I could be wrong.

Comment: Might have to agree with @MichaelHampton here. Also I no longer have access to this Rundeck as I now work somewhere else. I hope they solved the problem. Thank you for your answer, though you definitely shouldn't have to create a new project just for local jobs. Also to be honest, I think this job might have been in it's own project anyway (maybe).